# Can you explain the behavior of TextView + Gravity + SingleLine and Canvas?

Tags: android, canvas, textview

I have a custom TextView with it's `onDraw` method overridden to draw a red border around the text view.

When I set the *gravity to something else than left* **AND** *singleLine=true* : the border is not drawn.

- Is there any reason for that ?
- Is there any workaround ?

The following screenshot illustrate the problem : the second textView doesn't have a border
[image]

<sub>TL means TOP|LEFT ; C means CENTER ; SL means single-line ; T means true ; F means false</sub>

Here is the code (can be copy/pasted and run - no need for a layout file)

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    private final int TEXT_VIEW_WIDTH_PX = 400;
    private final int TEXT_VIEW_HEIGHT_PX = 60;
    private Paint borderPaint = new Paint();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        RelativeLayout rootView = new RelativeLayout(this);
        getWindow().setContentView(rootView);

        borderPaint.setColor(Color.RED);

        MyTextView text1 = makeTextView("Grav=TL ; SL=F",100);
        rootView.addView(text1);

        MyTextView text2 = makeTextView("Grav=C ; SL=T",200);
        //combination of the 2 following attributes cause the issue
        text2.setSingleLine(true);
        text2.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        rootView.addView(text2);

        MyTextView text3 = makeTextView("Grav=C ; SL=F",300);
        text3.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        rootView.addView(text3);

        MyTextView text4 = makeTextView("Grav=TL ; SL=T",400);
        text4.setSingleLine(true);
        rootView.addView(text4);
    }

    /**
     * Custom TextView with red border
     */
    private class MyTextView extends TextView {

        private MyTextView(Context context) {
            super(context);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            super.onDraw(canvas);
            canvas.drawLine(1,1,1,TEXT_VIEW_HEIGHT_PX-1,borderPaint);
            canvas.drawLine(1,1,TEXT_VIEW_WIDTH_PX-1,1,borderPaint);
            canvas.drawLine(TEXT_VIEW_WIDTH_PX-1,1,TEXT_VIEW_WIDTH_PX-1,TEXT_VIEW_HEIGHT_PX-1,borderPaint);
            canvas.drawLine(1,TEXT_VIEW_HEIGHT_PX-1,TEXT_VIEW_WIDTH_PX-1,TEXT_VIEW_HEIGHT_PX-1,borderPaint);
        }
    }


    /**
     * create a MyTextView with 'text' context and located at x=50 ; y=marginTop
     * (nothing relevant for the issue here)
     */
    private MyTextView makeTextView(String text, int marginTop){
        MyTextView textView = new MyTextView(this);
        textView.setText(text);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(TEXT_VIEW_WIDTH_PX,TEXT_VIEW_HEIGHT_PX);
        lp.topMargin = marginTop;
        lp.leftMargin = 50;
        textView.setLayoutParams(lp);
        return textView;
    }

}
```

Comment: Is the 4th `MyTextView` in the picture supposed to be "Grav=TL; SL=T" like in the code?

Comment: You are right, let me put the correct screenshot

Comment: i must have missed something but isn't it easier to setBackgroundDrawable?

Comment: @pskink Not sure I understand your point. I just want to draw the border. Using a 9 patch background can do the job if I only have one color (in my real code the color is dynamic and unknown at compile time so I cannot create the 9-patch corresponding to any possible color just to achieve this)

Comment: use Drawable.setColorFilter then

Comment: @pskink Sorry, but I don't see how to do that. Maybe can you elaborate in an answer presenting this workaround ?

Comment: for example d.setColorFilter(Color.RED, Mode.SRC_ATOP)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks to pskink's thorough research (from the comment on my another answer):

> If you want to know why custom `onDraw` doesn't draw anything, just `Log.d` the value of `canvas.getMatrix()`.
>
> [It] seems that canvas is translated/horizontally scrolled (at least in my case) 8159 pixels to the left, so calling `canvas.translate(8159, 0)` fixes the issue, of course 8159 is not a magic number and can vary.
>
> I found it, see `VERY_WIDE` constant in `TextView`, it is set to 16384 (2**14), in my case `TextView` has width of 66 and now (16384-66)/2 == 8159, voila!
>
> ...but VERY_WIDE is private so you cannot access it :-(

From here, I wonder if the offset can be retrieved programmatically, and sure it does, easily by `getScrollX()`. This approach translates the canvas instead of "hacking" the single-line by cancelling horizontal scrolled. It displays the single-line more naturally.

Inside custom `TextView`:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    // translate the canvas before drawing onto it, fixing the position
    canvas.translate(getScrollX(), 0);

    canvas.drawLine(1, 1, 1, TEXT_VIEW_HEIGHT_PX - 1, borderPaint);
    canvas.drawLine(1, 1, TEXT_VIEW_WIDTH_PX - 1, 1, borderPaint);
    canvas.drawLine(TEXT_VIEW_WIDTH_PX - 1, 1, TEXT_VIEW_WIDTH_PX - 1,
        TEXT_VIEW_HEIGHT_PX - 1, borderPaint);
    canvas.drawLine(1, TEXT_VIEW_HEIGHT_PX - 1, TEXT_VIEW_WIDTH_PX - 1,
        TEXT_VIEW_HEIGHT_PX - 1, borderPaint);
}
```

<sub>This code hasn't been tested thoroughly for all cases. I only confirmed the 4 cases provided by the OP</sub>

Comment: found "normal" and obvious (not hacky with getMatrix)  solution:  getScrollX() :-)

Comment: @pskink d'oh, I forgot about that. I should research more carefully instead of coding with what I only already know :)

Comment: honestly,  i didn't find it by analyzing  TextView code,  just was curious what is the value of getScrollX in that case and it turned out that it's the same number,  now i see the bringTextIntoView() method that calls scrollTo(),  take a look at it

Comment: It's possibly better to do this the way the View base class does : http://androidxref.com/4.4_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/view/View.java#14420

Answer (score 3):

### TL;DR

The problem seems to be from `setSingleLine()`. The workaround is to call `setHorizontallyScrolling(false)` after `setSingleLine(true)`, but this will "wrap" the text if it's too long. You can't even truncate it by using `setEllipsize()`; it doesn't have any effects.

```
MyTextView text2 = makeTextView(
    "Grav=C ; SL=T a ab abc abcd abcde abcdef abcdefg abcdefgh abcdefghi",
    200);
text2.setSingleLine(true);
text2.setHorizontallyScrolling(false);
text2.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
```

---

### Original Post

I still couldn't pinpoint the issue, but my guess is on the single-line.

When calling `text2.setSingleLine(true);`, Android will do this:

```
public void setSingleLine(boolean singleLine) {
    setInputTypeSingleLine(singleLine);
    applySingleLine(singleLine, true, true);
}

// no effect, since there is no editor
/*
private void setInputTypeSingleLine(boolean singleLine) {
    if (mEditor != null &&
            (mEditor.mInputType & EditorInfo.TYPE_MASK_CLASS) == EditorInfo.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT) {
        if (singleLine) {
            mEditor.mInputType &= ~EditorInfo.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_MULTI_LINE;
        } else {
            mEditor.mInputType |= EditorInfo.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_MULTI_LINE;
        }
    }
}
*/

private void applySingleLine(boolean singleLine, boolean applyTransformation,
        boolean changeMaxLines) {
    mSingleLine = singleLine;
    if (singleLine) {
        setLines(1);
        setHorizontallyScrolling(true);
        if (applyTransformation) {
            setTransformationMethod(SingleLineTransformationMethod.getInstance());
        }
    } else {
        if (changeMaxLines) {
            setMaxLines(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        }
        setHorizontallyScrolling(false);
        if (applyTransformation) {
            setTransformationMethod(null);
        }
    }
}
```

From here, I concluded that somewhere in `applySingleLine()` was causing this issue. Thus, I tried "simulating" the single-line by changing the code to below, and the issue is still there.

```
MyTextView text2 = makeTextView("Grav=C ; SL=T",200);
//text2.setSingleLine(true);
text2.setLines(1);
text2.setHorizontallyScrolling(true);
text2.setTransformationMethod(SingleLineTransformationMethod.getInstance());

text2.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
rootView.addView(text2);
```

But when I put `setHorizontallyScrolling(true)` into comment, the issue was gone! Thus, by calling `setHorizontallyScrolling(false)` after `setSingleLine(true)`, it negates the effect and solves the issue, but this will "wrap" the text if it's too long.

Comment: if you want to know why custom onDraw doesnt draw anything just Log.d the value of canvas.getMatrix()

Comment: @pskink Thanks for the input. I am still interested as why `setHorizontallyScrolling()` has anything to do with this issue... or was it just a red herring?

Comment: i think its not a red herring,  seems that canvas is translated/horizontally scrolled (at least in my case) 8159 pixels to the left, so calling canvas.translate(8159, 0) fixes the issue,  of course 8159 is not a magic number and can vary

Comment: i found it,  see VERY_WIDE constant in TextView,  it is set to 16384 (2**14), in my case TextView has width of 66 and now (16384-66)/2 == 8159, voila!

Comment: @pskink great ! so : if "horizontally scrolling" do a translation of (VERY_WIDE-textView.getWidth)/2 should solve the problem.

Comment: yes, but VERY_WIDE is private so you cannot access it :-(

Comment: and that's why i answered OP to use setBackgroundDrawable instead of overriding onDraw method

Comment: @pskink I added another answer using your approach, I hope you don't mind. Regarding OP's intention, perhaps using `setBackgroundDrawable` is the right way in this case, but he still got a point if he had to draw randomly on the canvas, which I think couldn't be achieved by `setBackgroundDrawable`...